# RequestParam get array from select option html form

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to get multiple values from a multiple select option box in html.

I get in to my controller:

```
/test?t=1&t=2&t=3
```

In the controller, I try to get the int array:

```
@RequestParam(value = "t", required = true) int[] t
```

But when I check it using:

```
t.length
```

I only see 1, which means Spring only gets 1 parameter, but I expected 3.
Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that spring will convert a parameter array to a specific type other than String, so you should try the following:

```
@RequestParam(value = "t", required = true) String[] t
```

and then use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the String to an int.

Answer (score 4):

This is working as expected with Spring 3.2 version.
I have a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blueprint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView blueprint(@RequestParam(value = "blueprints", required = false) int[] blueprints)
```

and when using

```
http://localhost:9000/blueprint?blueprints=2&blueprints=1
```

or

```
http://localhost:9000/nbu-portal-webapp/blueprint?blueprints=1,2
```

the values are being converted to the correct int array.